# How to show an alternative web structure when browsing a SharePoint site?

Tags: office-integration, webdav

I need to present an alternative web structure when browsing a SharePoint site in Windows Explorer file dialogs (based on some metadata like e.q. related department etc. and not the actual location path).

The real SharePoint web hierarchy may look like this `Web A > Web B > Web C`, which is reflected in the Explorer dialogs when browsing the site. I want to show an alternative virtual structure which could be `"Department A" > Web A, "Department A" > Web B, "Department B" > Web C` where the departments are not real webs but just logical folders presented when browsing the site.

I have been looking at the protocol documentation ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250046(prot.20).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj557055(office.12).aspx)), but it is sparsomme at best, and from what I can tell it doesn't look like I can intercept the way SharePoint communicates with the OS via WebDAV.

**Is it possible to intercept the SP WebDAV protocol somehow and present an alternative hierarchy?**

If there is a completely different approach to a solution here, or you have any experience with attempting something similar, your response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What we use for this kind of requirements is to run a JavaScript code in the master page to get user's department and redirect it to the relevant hierarchy. Department vs Department Home Page URLs are kept in a list so that they can be modified without editing the code.